# Visual Studio OData "Add Service Reference" code-gen failing

Tags: c#, web-services, odata, data.gov

[This data.gov website](https://data.cms.gov/Medicare/Inpatient-Prospective-Payment-System-IPPS-Provider/97k6-zzx3) gives an OData data export with instructions to use the link [`http://data.cms.gov/OData.svc/97k6-zzx3`](http://data.cms.gov/OData.svc/97k6-zzx3)

[image: https://data.cms.gov/Medicare/Inpatient-Prospective-Payment-System-IPPS-Provider/97k6-zzx3 screenshot]

(After Nugeting [`Install-Package Microsoft.Data.Services.Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client/) version 5.6.1)  I attempt to use the full link to "Add Service Reference" to my C# project in either Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013, I get `There was an error downloading 'http://data.cms.gov/OData.svc/97k6-zzx3/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found. ...`

[image: Visual Studio error message 1]

If I truncate the URL to [`http://data.cms.gov/OData.svc`](http://data.cms.gov/OData.svc) then I get one step further, but still an error `The custom tool 'DataServicesCoreClientGenerator' failed.  Data service client code-generation failed:  Schema specified is not valid.  Errors: ... The 'Name' attribute is invalid - the value '97k6-zzx3' is invalid according to its datatype` (I suppose since C# identifiers cannot begin with digits)

[image: Visual Studio error message 2]

Is this a bug with data.cms.gov or Visual Studio (etc)?  Is there a close workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`https://data.cms.gov/OData.svc/$metadata`](https://data.cms.gov/OData.svc/%24metadata). Code-generation needs metadata, the above URL will provide that.

The URL [`https://data.cms.gov/OData.svc`](https://data.cms.gov/OData.svc) is the service document, not metadata.

Comment: @Dan - Thanks, but trying that url shows no change in behavior.  I'm not really surprised either because the Add Service Reference dialog has long been able to guess at the metadata (ie `?wsdl`) and the dialog in this case still is able to show the Service and all of its different "operations" in the tree.  But when I say "OK" to *yes, please generate the service reference for this selected service* it fails with the error in that last image of my post.

Comment: Sorry @uosɐſ, I was just correcting Maya's answer for clarity. Regardless, I've had success consuming (and exposing) WCF OData services in the past; I vaguely recall the process for adding the service reference to an OData service being slightly different (IIRC, which I might not) Let me dig around for an old project.

Comment: Oh, whoops!  Yes, that shoulda been addressed to Maya - my bad @Maya.  Thanks, Dan.  I suspect this is a service-specific problem because the service names begin with digits.  But I'll have no luck if I wait for data.gov to address *that*.  Hopefully you guys have a trick up your collective sleeve.

Comment: Sorry that I did not see the attached picture last night... I just review the metadata of [https://data.cms.gov/OData.svc/$metadata](https://data.cms.gov/OData.svc/$metadata). Yes, there are some name of entity set and property are not valid according to the OData protocol...If you try [http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/$metadata](http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/$metadata). There are no problem.